# A = ( ( b <= c) || (b > c) )

Tags: integer, logic

I'm working on simple logical quiz lately and faced with this. Been working around integer but i can't find the answer. What would be the value of A if Given A = ( ( b <= c) || (b > c) )?

*Edit : I'm sorry for the unclear description. The condition that asked is like this

```
    If ( var1 <= 10 || var1 > 10){
        print "wrong"
    }else{
        print "true"
```

Comment: Either `true` or `false`, appears that will always be `true`.

Comment: Depends on the language.  In most languages you will get an implicit conversion error.  In those that allow it, you'll probably get either True or -1 or 1, depending on the language specifics.

Comment: Has to be true no matter what the value of b and c.

Comment: What is `var1`? If var 1 is integer, 'wrong' is the output. If this is code, and if `var1` is not defined, you will get an error because we cannot compare `nil`, `undefined` values with integers.

Comment: the var1 is integer. The thing is i need to know what is the value of var1

Comment: A will be true always

Answer (score 0):

In C, your code will always give 'false', since the first condition covers all possible values of var1.